# How can i make input this array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a problem adding this array in a mysql database someone could help me? i think the  problem is to identify the id of the array to input into the database.

```
<html>
```

```
    <title> Registro do Pedido </title>
```

```
    <body>

                <h2> REGISTRE O PEDIDO</h2>

                <form action="teste1.php" method="post">    
                <p align = "left">  

                    Product 1:<input type="text" name="product1" ></br></br>
                    Quantity:<input type="int" name="quantidade1" ></br></br>
                    price:<input type="text" name="price1" ></br></br>
                    Product 2:<input type="text" name="product2" ></br></br>
                    Quantity:<input type="int" name="quantidade2" ></br></br>
                    price:<input type="text" name="price2" ></br></br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Registrar Pedido">


    </body>
```

i need to add a for a client more than one procut and describe each quantity and price so i can calculate the total price how can i do that?

```
    <?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$addproduct[1]=array(
    'produto'=> '$_POST[product1]',
    'quant'=>'$_POST[quantidade1]',
    'price'=>'$_POST[price1]'
);
$addproduct[2]=array(
    'produto'=> '$_POST[product2]',
    'quant'=>'$_POST[quantidade2]',
    'price'=>'$_POST[price2]'
);
$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (produto, quantidade, preco)
VALUES ('$addproduto[][produto]', '$addproduto[][quant]', '$addproduto[][price]')";
?>
```

Comment: this is not how you add multiple rows in 1 query.

Comment: how can i do that?my problem is that i want to have just one id order and mutiple products

Comment: 1st your question is not clear on what u want & what is problem now. But that u mentioned in comment, i guess i know what you need. i shouldn't answer but i'll try to help u in this. You need 2 tables `one to many` relation. With one table, u simply need to add each array item with same `order id` with quries in loop.

Answer (score 1):

This answer scales well if you want to offer more than 2 product entries, for example 3, 4 or 5 products to be added at once

**HTML**

```
<?php $num_products = 2; ?>

<h2> REGISTRE O PEDIDO</h2>

<form action="teste1.php" method="post">    
    <p align = "left">  
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_products; $i++) { ?>
        Product <?php echo $i; ?>:<input type="text" name="product[]" ></br></br>
        Quantity:<input type="int" name="quantidade[]" ></br></br>
        Price:<input type="text" name="price[]" ></br></br>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar Pedido">
    </p>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $produto = isset($_POST['product']) ? $_POST['product'] : array();
    $quant = isset($_POST['quantidade']) ? $_POST['quantidade'] : array();
    $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : array();

    if (is_array($produto) && count($produto) > 0) {
        // Create a unique order number
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO orders SET orderid = NULL, dateadded = NOW()';
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $orderid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

        for ($i = 0, $j = count($produto); $i < $j; $i++) {
            if (isset($quant[$i]) && isset($price[$i])) {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO produtos (orderid, itemid, produto, quantidade, preco) VALUES (' . $orderid . ', NULL, "' . mysql_real_escape_string($produto[$i]) . '", "' . ((int) $quant[$i]) . '", "' . ((float) $price[$i]) . '")';
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Later on if you know the Order ID you can get the total value of all products for that order:

```
SELECT SUM(preco) FROM produtos WHERE orderid = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get the total price for each item in the array, i would another element, like so:

```
$addproduct[1]=array(
'produto'=> '$_POST[product1]',
'quant'=>'$_POST[quantidade1]',
'price'=>'$_POST[price1]',
'total'=> '$_POST[quantidade1] * $_POST[price1]'
);
```

The other thing that I think you're trying to do is insert this into a database, and you have more than one item, so you need a multi-insert statement, like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos (produto, quantidade, preco)
VALUES 
('$addproduto[1][produto]', '$addproduto[1][quant]','$addproduto[1][price]'),
('$addproduto[2][produto]', '$addproduto[2][quant]', '$addproduto[2][price]')";
```

I'm not a PHP developer, so you need to double check the syntax on the array elements that I added and whether or not that would work and calculate the total value for each item.